# Connect to MySql Database with Hostgator

Tags: php, mysql, web-services

I recently bought a hosting plan from Hostgator and I have a few PHP files that I put on the site using CyberDuck. They obviously got uploaded because when I visit my domain I get the error: `Connection failed: SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'gator4066.hostgator.com' (using password: YES)`. I need to connect to my MySQL database but I'm not sure how. This is how my `database.php` files looks:

```
<?php
  $server = 'theServerIPThatHostGatorSentMeInEmail';
  $username = 'root'; // for the database on my PC
  $password = 'myPassword'; // for the database on my PC
  $database = 'auth'; // the name of the database on my PC

  try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$server;dbname=$database;", $username, $password);
  } catch(PDOException $e) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage());
  }
?>
```

I'm not sure if I need to use some other `username/password/databaseName`.

I'd just like to mention that this all works with `localhost`, so everything is set up properly apart from connecting through the domain).

Comment: https://www.hostgator.com/help/article/how-do-i-create-a-mysql-database-a-user-and-then-delete-if-needed

Comment: try to use localhost instead of any strict IP if you db and script exist at the same server

Comment: Also avoid to use root user for general database access, instead create another one for web script

Comment: Why did you use 'theServerIPThatHostGatorSentMeInEmail', but left the user, password, and DB name set to "// for the database on my PC".  

That's a simple mistake ... should be simple to fix.  Use the username, password, and db name for the hostgator database instead.

Answer (score 0):

Many hostgator accounts have your php and web server running on the same machine as your MySQL server.    And, it's extraordinarily unlikely that you, as a hostgator customer, can use the MySQL root account; it would allow you to see other customers' data.

Hostgator has lots of customers on each machine, sharing it. (Possibly too many, but that's a question for another day.)

So, your configuration is likely to be something like this:

```
 $server = 'localhost';
 $username = 'SOMETHING-SET-UP-IN-YOUR-CONTROL-PANEL'; 
 $password = 'SOMETHING-SET-UP-IN-YOUR-CONTROL-PANEL'; 
 $database = 'yourCustomerName-SOMETHING';
```

Comment: Yep this was it, however it was the server IP, not locahost. Thanks!